Keep your ----- ◯ and find the answer!
Which option, A-G, must replace the question mark for this grid of names to be complete? Explain why.
                   ◯ __________________________________________________
                    |
                    |Isaac       Raphael     Cain     Paolo     Austen
                    | 
                    |Beatrice    Reese       Freida     ?       Reuben
                    |
                    |Mariah      Gabriel     Bashiir  Violet    Julius
                    |
                    |Joanne      Khloe       Antoine  Woody     Douglas
                    |        
                    |Eduard      Veronique   Quincy   Phuong    Luuk



                  Option, 

                  A: Abigail
                  
                  B: Briannah

                  C: Charles

                  D: Dawoud
          
                  E: Ethelle

                  F: Fiona

                  G: George


Damn it. I made one mistake, Can't edit now since it would reveal the method I used to create it. But I'm sure you can get the right answer anyways (ignoring that mistake). I'll make an edit once someone has given me the correct answer.

The words in the grid contain

 aa ae ai ao au
 ea ee ei ?? eu
 ia ie ii io iu
 oa oe oi oo ou
 ua ue ui uo uu

So a name which fits is

 George


Note that the error spoken of is in the bottom row of the 4th column.

This is correct. Well done!

What about the title?

@ACB - I don't know. A guess is rot13(zbhgu bcra gb pyhr ibjryf)

Yes that was exactly my intention with the title
